# What sets the maximum spin rate for a star?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, astrophysics

Is it just the relativistic limit of $v<c$?

Comment: I suppose you're asking about stars that are primarily composed of degenerate matter, like white dwarfs and neutron stars, since main sequence stars don't spin all that fast. Eg, the equatorial speed of the Sun is 1.997 km/s.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean what is the maximum rotation rate for a star I should answer that it is related to the Keplerian break-up rotation rate and it is:

$$Ω_K = \left(\frac{GM}{r^3}\right)^{\frac 1 2}$$

It is the maximum velocity that a star can reach without losing mass because of centrifugal acceleration. 
If the star is a fast rotator you should consider that $r_{\text{pole}} =2/3 r_{\text{equator}}$ where $r$ is the radius of the star. 
For example, a star with $Ω/Ω_K > 0.8$ is a very fast-rotating star. 
$Ω$ is the projected rotational velocity ($v \sin i$) in the line of the sight of the observer and $i$ is the inclination of the rotation axis according to the observer.